# Computing hamming distances on large data set

Tags: python, csv, hamming-distance

I have an input file of about 10^5 rows.
Each row is a sequence of 24 bits, i.e.:

`1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0`

I need to compute the Hamming Distance for every pair of rows.
Here's my first implementation using SciPy hamming function:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import hamming

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
    nodes = {}
    b = 24  # Number of bits
    for nodeNum, node in enumerate(reader):
        node[nodeNum] = [int(i) for i in node]

for u, uBits in nodes.items():
    for v, vBits in nodes.items():
        distance = hamming(uBits, vBits) * b
            # Do stuff
```

Second implementation I came up with:

`node[nodeNum] = sum([int(bit)*2**power for power, bit in enumerate(node)])`

Here I only store the decimal value but I then have to manually count set bits resulting from each XOR operation:

```
def hamming(a, b):
    N = a ^ b

    distance = 0
    ptr = 1

    while N:
        distance += ((N + 1) //
                           2 * ptr)
        N -= (N + 1) // 2
        ptr += 1

    return distance
```

How can I improve my code (both in terms of memory usage and runtime, ideally)?

Comment: Do you need to iterate over every pair? The number of pairs would strike me as the bottleneck, not the implementation of your Hamming distance function.

Comment: The rest of my code is using Single Link Clustering to find the largest k such that there exists a k-clustering with a spacing of at least 3. I don't think I can avoid checking every pair's distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the fastest you can do (watchout, for your data size it'd require to allocate 74.5 GiB of memory):

```
import numpy as np

nodes = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
    for node in reader:
        nodes.append([int(i) for i in node])

dists = 2 * np.inner(nodes-0.5, 0.5-nodes) + nodes.shape[1] / 2
```

Just for fun, here is a 40X faster version in Julia:

```
using LoopVectorization, Tullio

function hamming!(nodes,dists)
    @tullio dists[i,j] = sum(nodes[i,k] ⊻ nodes[j,k])
end

n = 10^5
nodes = rand(Int8[0,1],n,24)
dists = Matrix{Int8}(undef,n,n)
@time hamming!(nodes,dists) # Run twice
  # 1.886367 seconds (114 allocations: 6.594 KiB)
```

While we're at it, I invite you to enter the world of Julia. It offers similar speeds to C++ and a pleasant syntax similar to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put the whole .csv into an array and then let `scipy` do all the work of computing pairwise distances?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.spatial.distance

nodes = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
    for node in reader:
        nodes.append([int(i) for i in node])

nodes = np.array(nodes)  # not strictly necessary
dists = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(nodes, 'hamming')
```